# How can I reduce the file size of my forge extension (.xif)?

Tags: outsystems

I have created an [extension for the forge](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component/2341/textmod/) but the file size is extreme at ~2.9MB. How can I reduce the file size?

I have removed all unnecessary references etc. but the size remains high.

There is also no help in the documentation on this or any post on the OutSystems forum that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, 2.9Mb is big but not necessarily prohibitively big for an extension.

In any case, the XIF is a fairly optimised format so, if you have that size, it's because you must be including a fair amount of resources.

On the Resources tab (second of the left panel in Integration studio), make sure you "Exclude from Extension" everything that's not necessary, like unneeded assemblies, PDFs that document included assemblies or even source files.

Depending on the XIF, you *may* only need the DLL of the compiled extension, inside the Bin/ directory.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I have actually made sure to exclude all unnecessary items. I have a theory on what went "wrong" - I hope to recreate the scenario and post the answer here.